# Program crashes with WebKit Previewer example with on_textEdit_textChanged()

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I recreated the example of a webkit that displays the content of a textEdit containing HTML: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/webkit-previewer.html

I changed it so rather than the webkit HTML being changed upon clicking the button, it's changed upon the text in the textEdit being changed:

```
// changed when button is click. Works fine.
void Previewer::on_previewButton_clicked()
{
    // Update the contents in web viewer
    QString text = htmlTextEdit->toPlainText();
    webView->setHtml(text);
}

// change when text is changed. Crashes.
void Previewer::on_htmlTextEdit_textChanged()
{
    // Update the contents in web viewer
    QString text = "<html><body><h1>No crash!</h1></body></html>";
    webView->setHtml(text);
}
```

This causes the program to crash as soon as it starts. I altered the program to run the function only a bit later (I thought maybe something needed to be initialized) but it still crashed once it reached the textChanged function. Why is it crashing? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is entering an infinite loop because, in the example, there's a connection between the webView's `loadFinished(bool)` signal and the text/html editor's `updateTextEdit()` slot.

Basically, editing the HTML causes the page to load again, which causes an update to the editor, which causes the page to load again, so on and so forth.

A quick way I solved this was to add a static bool flag to the `updateTextEdit` SLOT/function that only allows it to run once.

```
 void MainWindow::updateTextEdit()
 {
     static bool once = false;

     if (once) {
         return;
     }

     once = true;

     QWebFrame *mainFrame = centralWidget->webView->page()->mainFrame();
     QString frameText = mainFrame->toHtml();
     centralWidget->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(frameText);
 }
```

Doing this worked for me, but your version might work differently than mine.  I followed the example closely, but added an `htmlchanged()` slot to the previewer class, and made the connection like so:

```
connect(centralWidget->plainTextEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), centralWidget, SLOT(html_changed()));
```

Also, I'm no expert, but I'm pretty sure this is not the best way to get around this, and I assume that `updateTextEdit()` needs to run more than once.  It'll work for the time being, though.